# json change dictionary item to a list with one dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm working with a Rest Api for finding address details. I pass it an address and it passes back details for that address: lat/long, suburb etc. I'm using the requests library with the json() method on the response and adding the json response to a list to analyse later.

What I'm finding is that when there is a single match for an address the 'FoundAddress' key in the json response contains a dictionary but when more than one match is found the 'FoundAddress' key contains a list of dictionaries.

The returned json looks something like:

For a single match:

```
{
'FoundAddress': {AddressDetails...}
}
```

For multiple matches:

```
{
'FoundAddress': [{Address1Details...}, {Address2Details...}]
}
```

I don't want to write code to handle a single match and then multiple matches.

How can I modify the 'FoundAddress' so that when there is a single match it changes it to a list with a single dictionary entry? Such that I get something like this:

```
{
'FoundAddress': [{AddressDetails...}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the external API sending responses in that format then you can't really change `FoundAddress` itself, since it will always arrive in that format.

You can change the response if you want to, since you have full control over what you've received:

```
r = json.parse(response)
fixed = r['FoundAddress'] if (type(r['FoundAddress']) is list) else [r['FoundAddress']]
r['FoundAddress'] = fixed
```

Alternatively you can do the distinction at address usage time:

```
def func(foundAddress):
   # work with a single dictionary instance here
```

then:

```
result = map(func, r['FoundAddress']) if (type(r['FoundAddress']) is list) else [func(r['FoundAddress'])]
```

But honestly I'd take a clear:

```
if type(r['FoundAddress']) is list:
   result = map(func, r['FoundAddress'])
else:
   result = func(r['FoundAddress'])
```

or the response fix-up over the `a if b else c` one-liner any day.

Comment: Thanks heaps! The top code block worked a treat. Any reason in particular you'd prefer the latter approach?

Comment: @Oaty I can't think of a situation where I'd prefer to constantly discern between a list and a single item as opposed to fixing the response once and always working with the fixed response, so the first suggestion is what I'd also use. The final paragraph was about `map(func, r['FoundAddress']) if (type(r['FoundAddress']) is list) else [func(r['FoundAddress'])]` being not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would just change the API. If you can't there's nothing magical you can do. You just have to handle the special case. You could probably do this in one place in your code with a function like:

```
def handle_found_addresses(found_addresses):
    if not isinstance(found_addresses, list):
        found_addresses = [found_addreses]
         ...
```

and then proceed from there to do whatever you do with found addresses as if the value is always a list with one or more items.